# "user was removed" ¿Es posible saber quién?

Tags: discusión

Hoy encontré en mi reputación 3 novedades debido a "user was removed": -10 +2 -10

Se que se trata de un usuario que se elimina por cualquier motivo del sistema y sus votaciones ya no son válidas pero, a manera de chisme ¿es posible saber cuál fué el usuario eliminado?

Me imagino que es el mismo usuario que estaba incomodando a Carlos Alejo.

Me causa curiosidad y me gustaría saber quien era.

Comment: La verdad es que no sé si estoy autorizado a dar esta información. Este usuario decidió pedir que se eliminara su cuenta sin avisar más que a Stack Exchange (no nos lo dijo a nosotros, sino que envió un mensaje a la empresa, cuyos empleados fueron los que lo hicieron -y yo lo vi por casualidad). Por tanto, si lo llevó con tanta discrección no quiero ser yo quien lo diga : )

Comment: Sí, se trata del mismo usuario, aunque respeto su privacidad y no siento curiosidad por saber quién es. El caso es que es una lástima, porque había recibido muchos votos negativos suyos pero también muchos positivos. De hecho, su ida me causó -95 puntos de reputación. Por lo que sí siento curiosidad es por saber el motivo por el cual pasó de votarme positivo a negativo, y me gustaría saberlo por tener la oportunidad de reparar el agravio que pude hacerle y para no repetir esos errores en el futuro.

Comment: Por cierto, "Alejo" es mi apellido, podéis llamarme simplemente Carlos. :)

Comment: @Carlos precisamente este es un caso muy representativo de _serial voting_. Me parece que lo impulsó conseguir las medallas Suffrage y Vox Populi, por lo que votó [negativamente] de forma indiscriminada. De ahí que esos votos es bueno que se hayan ido, pues no se basaban en la calidad de la publicación sino en puras cosas vanas.